# NodeJS Buffer is not Garbage Collected

Tags: node.js, garbage-collection, buffer

I have a NodeJS script which spawns ffmpeg and ffplay and then takes frames from the input ffmpeg, processes them and outputs them to another ffmpeg and ffplay. It works and process 1080p about 3 frames per second, but for some reason it keeps the buffers around after they are written to the output. This happens whether I use cluster workers or not, but if I do, the workers also start using a lot of memory.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It uses a generational garbage collector. This means it that it divides the heap in multiple areas and uses a bunch of specialized algorithms to manage them - a "nursery" for short-lived objects, which is most allocations, and one or more areas for longer-lived objects that have survived the nursery.

The nursery uses an algorithm whose execution is proportional to the number of live objects, meaning doesn't pay any price for garbage, but requires double the memory (on collection, it just abandons one half of the memory and copies all live objects to the other).

The old-areas use mark & sweep or mark & compact, which incrementally mark live objects, starting from the roots (global references, the stack, etc.), while the program is executing and new allocations and changes to pointers are happening (using dark magic). Eventually it starts freeing dead objects, meaning all objects that didn't get marked, also incrementally, in order to not cause a large pause (making the correct observation that all the free memory is not required right now - as long as it's being freed up faster than the space is being filled).

The above is from this [quora answer](https://www.quora.com/How-does-garbage-collector-in-Node-js-reclaim-buffer-memory-as-it-is-assigned-out-of-VM-memory-heap).

Answer (score 0):

In certain cases, Node.js garbage collection runs when V8 memory usage reaches `max-old-space-size`. This is V8's heap memory limit (default is 1.4GB or so). For us to be able to help you, you should post some of your code. It would also help to know what version of Node.js you are running.

You can run your script and set `max-old-space-size` to a really low number to make sure GC actually runs. If it runs then your code is fine, and your problem is caused by Node.js GC optimizations...

Comment: Thank you. In this case, it turns out I was consuming data faster than I was putting it out. So it piled up in memory.

Comment: In other words, I was reading ffmpeg.stdout, but not pausing it correctly when I needed to while the output ffmpeg was consuming the data I was giving it.

Comment: I see, glad you figured it out. There's a lot of blog posts on the internet of people having issues with Node.js GC not running until a lot of memory is used, thought you might be having the same issue...